# wowza cloud live streaming is not working

Tags: android, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'm using Wowza streaming cloud it works fine using HLS link on the web but an android device not working on the web view.can you anyone me how its work.

And rtsp live link also not working on android device

public class AnotherOne extends AppCompatActivity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{

```
private String Downloadurl;
private int playminute;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
ProgressBar p_bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another_one);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);


    Downloadurl = "https://7c6ad8.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com/app-04be/ngrp:f23a3900_all/playlist.m3u8";
    // Description =  getIntent().getStringExtra("Description");
    Log.e("kanish","Download Url inside player:"+Downloadurl);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   // p_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Downloadurl);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(AnotherOne.this);
        //mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //p_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you share the link? we can help you more efficiently if you share the codes and efforts you made.

Comment: Actually, it an IP address, once we start it will create a new ip  liknk, is(rtsp://xxx.xxxx.xxx:1935/live/3cb11d45)

Comment: 1.it must be m3u8 file(link)    2.Follow the code i posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare a  view to render video View and 
You need to use Media Player Api Provided by Android to Stream m3u8.it is pretty Simple to play Live content follow this code.

```
   public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {


   private String Downloadurl;
   private int playminute;
   private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
   private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
   private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
   ProgressBar p_bar;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);


    Downloadurl = "YOUR M3U8 URL";
    // Description =  getIntent().getStringExtra("Description");
       Log.e("kanish","Download Url inside player:"+Downloadurl);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(PlayerActivity.this);
    }

     @Override
     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    p_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Downloadurl);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(PlayerActivity.this);
        //mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    }

   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    p_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
       releaseMediaPlayer();
      }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
     }

   private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
      if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
  }

}
```

Let me Know if it helps.

Comment: it's not working sir.I'm getting this error. LiveSession: unable to fetch master playlist https://<suppressed>.

Comment: Can you share your code .Plus please post your stack trace .

Comment: I'll post it on above sir9

Comment: the m3u8 link you posted is not supported ,Mediaplayer throwing error of MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004) which means Media content is unsupported ,digging it little more ,it seems the video at wowza cloud is not delivering HLS chunks from Hls playist.

Comment: yeah sir, but I have used rtsp link in Wowza cloud that's also getting the same error

Comment: check your setup at wowza cloud.Also you can Use EXoMedia to play this.Please upvote the answer if it helped you :)